# Cakephp input box with enum function in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have enum function in some of the rows and was wondering how we could fetch this in Cake to view it as select box?

Below is the function example:

```
enum('Uusi hakija','Jatkohakemus','40+','60+','Työyhteisöhanke','Mieshanke','Urheiluseurahanke')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$enumList = enum('Your', 'stuff', 'goes', 'here');
$vars = explode('.', $enumList);

$this->Form->select('Model.field_name', $vars);
```

Very simple but should work.  Your `option` names would be `0`, `1`, `2`, etc.

Check out CakePHP's [FormHelper](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1383/Form) and [the `select` input](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1430/select).

Comment: you could also use this approach for enums (a little bit cleaner): http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/24/static-enums-or-semihardcoded-attributes/

Answer (score 1):

The proper "Cake" way of doing this would be to use the Array Datasource from the [official datasources plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources).

You setup a model for your enum data and assign all the normal relationships. To set the data set the records property in your model like so:

```
public $records = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'stuff'),
    array('id' => '2')
);
```